# Can these two answers be merged?

Tags: support

With reference to [What is a good text editor for developing code on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/10998/25656), I want to suggest that two answers, both relating to Geany be merged.
The answers are
https://askubuntu.com/a/11007/25656
and
https://askubuntu.com/a/3785/25656.

Answer (score 3):

We can't merge answers like that. We can edit them... But so can you.

Why don't you just improve the accepted answer? If you think it's missing useful information that from the other post, add it in.